# How to plot a horizontal line when my buy condition met till my sell conditions met?

Tags: pine-script

How to plot a horizontal line from close of candle where buy condition triggered till close of one candle before where sell conditions signal.

Answer (score 0):

Use the style=plot.style_linebr from the plot function

```
plot(strategy.position_size > 0 ? close : na, title = "Close Long", color = color.fuchsia, linewidth=2, style=plot.style_linebr)
```

Comment: Thank you for help, but I am asking for an Indicator.